# How to save memory inside hashtable?

Tags: c, data-structures, hash

In my structure `struct ListNode` I am making a int type variable key but it is necessary to make that in the `struct Listnode` can we make that inside `HashTableNode` because when two or more items will be there in `HashTableNode` (that is when collision will be more in single table node) than we have to create more linked list node and every time inside that node key variable will consume some memory if we can define that inside HashTableNode than we can save memory.

Is it correct to mention the key in each list node so that we can access at any time whenever  we need because the below hash table implementation is from very famous book of data structures.

Please tell me what i mentioned above is correct
Because i am a beginner if Not then please correct me

```
#define Load_factor 20
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Listnode{
 int key;
 int data;
 struct Listnode* next;
};
struct HashTableNode{
 int bcount;          /// Number of elements in block
 struct Listnode* next;
 };
struct HashTable{
 int tsize;          /// Table size
 int count;
 struct HashTableNode** Table;
};
struct HashTable* createHashTable(int size){
 struct HashTable* h;
 h=(struct HashTable*)malloc(sizeof(struct HashTable));
 h->tsize=size/Load_factor;
 h->count=0;

 h->Table=(struct HashTableNode**)malloc(sizeof(struct HashTableNode*)*h->tsize);
 if(!h->Table){
 printf("Memory Error");
  return NULL;
 }
 for(int i=0;i<h->tsize;i++){
 h->Table[i]->bcount=0;
 h->Table[i]->next=NULL;
 }
   return h;
 }
int HASH(int  data,int tsize){
return(data%tsize);
}
/// Hashsearch
int HashSearch(struct HashTable* h,int data){
  struct Listnode* temp;
  temp=h->Table[HASH(data,h->tsize)]->next;
  while(temp)     ///same as temp!=NULL
  {
   if(temp->data==data)
      return 1;
    temp=temp->next;
  }
    return 0;

}

int HashDelete(struct HashTable* h,int  data)
{
 int index;
 struct Listnode *temp,*prev;
 index=HASH(data,h->tsize);
 for(temp=h->Table[index]->next,prev=NULL;temp;prev=temp,temp=temp->next)
 {
    if(temp->data==data)
    {
        if(prev!=NULL)
             prev->next=temp->next;
         free(temp);
         h->Table[index]->bcount--;
         h->count--;
         return 1;
    }
 }

 return 0;

}
int HashInsert(struct HashTable *h ,int data){
 int index;
 struct Listnode* temp,*newnode;
 if(HashSearch(h,data))
    return 0;
 index = HASH(data,h->tsize);
 temp=h->Table[index]->next;
 newnode=(struct Listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct Listnode));
 if(!newnode)
    return -1;
 newnode->key=index;
 newnode->data;
 newnode->next=h->Table[index]->next;
 h->Table[index]->next=newnode;
 h->Table[index]->bcount++;
 h->count++;
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to store key for every node because it is used to resolve collisions. Please note that the collision happens to the **hash value** and **not** the key, which means that every element (`Listnode`) in the same bucket (`HashTableNode`) will still have a different key so you can't optimize it away.

However, in your example **the data is the key** (which is usually called a HashSet as opposed to HashMap), so there is really no need for the `key` field in the `Listnode`.

Comment: I am confused in `key` and `index` because in my code key is assigned to index can you explain it

Comment: @david12345, please see the updated answer. Also the fact that the index is stored to the `key` field doesn't really make sense to me either.